# Why fread returns Zero and when the files has contents

Tags: c, file, structure, binaryfiles, symbol-table

im trying to read a content of the file "sym.dat" even thru file has contents fread returns zero and i tried using ferror too but it didnt show any error.

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("sym.dat","ab");

struct node a;
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET); 

while((fread(&a,sizeof(struct node),1,fp))==1)
{

printf("bello");

}}
```

it returns 0

Comment: When `fread` returns zero, have you tried to check `feof` or `ferror` to see why?

Comment: You should open the file in `rb` mode, not `ab`. `ab` is for writing, not reading, and it positions to the end of the file.

Comment: You're certain the file which "has contents" is in the current working directory?

Comment: i tried with feof and ferror but it didnt shown any erro . i have to read a contents of the file and append some content to it. thats why i used ab mode. @Barmar

Comment: are you sure you even open the file ? because you read it why you do not open it with "rb" flags ? you do not check result of _fopen_. Why calling _fseek_ ?

Comment: i have already inserted some contents in sym.dat. i just tried to move fseek to beginning of the file. and i opened a file called sym.dat and it works perfectly in other functions except this one @bruno

Comment: @mystica you open the file to **write** in it, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doing

> ```
>  fp=fopen("sym.dat","ab");
> ```

you open the file to *write* in it from its end, not to *read* in it, so the test in `while((fread(&a,sizeof(struct node),1,fp))==1)` is immediately false and you do not print "bello"

do

```
fp=fopen("sym.dat","rb");
```

and check *fp* is not NULL.

The *fseek* is useless, when you open it you are at its beginning

Do not forget to close the file

---

If you need to read and write in it open it with the flags "rb+", the *fseek* is still useless.

Comment: thanks for it. but i want to search and insert record in the binary file. is it okay to use rb+ then

Comment: @mystica Yes it is okay using rb+, as I said in my answer